# Cannot put a local file URL in card description in Trello

Tags: url, trello-cards

I have seen that other users can link to local files from a card, using Markdown syntax.

I can do it in a comment (writing directly the `file:///` URL) but I would like to do it in the card description. In this field I can put an URL to internet content, but I have not been able to do it for local content.

I write in card description this:

```
[File](file:///c:/Unidad%20E/User/Documentos/servicios%20interactivos/Autoescuela/desarrollo/dise%C3%B1o%20gr%C3%A1fico/FileName.pdf)
```

When I save the description, the word "File" is showed as a link, but when I click on it, Trello opens again the card description box for editing.

Is it a specific problem for this field?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the `file:///` syntax is supported.

I tried Markdown and "plain text" formatting in the description and checklist items using `file:///`, mapped drive and UNC syntaxes, unfortunately none of the combinations worked.

Typing a web address (`http://`) into a description or a checklist item works (even without Markdown, which checklists don't support), so probably they'd have to add support for the `file:///` syntax (either directly or add it to Markdown).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer can be found here: http://help.trello.com/article/1040-why-cant-i-open-file-links

This is from their site:

> If you need to reference a specific shared drive file, you can paste a
>   link to that file (such as file://F/image.png) in a card comment or
>   description.
>
> When that link is clicked on, Trello will prompt you to copy the link
>   and paste it in to your own browser. (For security reasons, Trello is
>   not able to directly open file protocols other than http://, https://,
>   or mailto:.) Your computer will then try to open the file.
>
> For ftp:// links specifically, your browser should try to open them
>   directly if you click on them in the card description or comments.